# Excel two column reference third for answer

Tags: microsoft-excel

Any help is appreciated, trying to pull data from the first spreadsheet and I have to match two columns (D and E exactly) on the data sheet to two columns (C and D) on the destination sheet.  The returned data on the destination sheet (column G) should be the number found in F on the data sheet.

### data sheet:

[image: data sheet]

### data destination:

[image: data destination]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use an array formula:

```
=INDEX('datasheet'!$F$1:$F$1000,MATCH(1,(C2 = 'datasheet'!$D$1:$D$1000)*(D2 = 'datasheet'!$E$1:$E$1000),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

If you want to avoid the array formula then on the datasheet in the second row an empty column (I will use column H for this example) put the following formula:

```
=D2 & "}}}" & E2
```

Copy/Drag it down the entirety of the data.

Then on your output sheet in G2:

```
=INDEX('datasheet'!$F:$F,MATCH(C2 & "}}}" & D2,'datasheet'!$H:$H,0))
```

And copy/drag down.

Comment: Great solution with index match, kept trying that but never got anywhere close, FIRST ARRAY use.  Multi column vlookup would be perfect. Seems to copy down easily.  Some formula issues copying across columns. Any thoughts on making that easier???